# Getting unwanted mails

Tags: php, spam, malware

Receiving malicious and unwanted e-mails from various sites.receiver mails are like

- byYiOVF.at.mydomain.com
- GyaPbMox.at.mydomain.com

But as they does not exist the mails are bounced back to my google apps admin mailbox.Searched and scanned my domain files for spam,malware by AVG,Norton,McAfee etc. but found all OK.

What may be the reason?Please suggest.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question is off topic for this site, but the issue is pretty common. You'll just have to spam-filter them like everyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I think your question is off topic, here is an answer that might help you a bit:

You might be a victim of a mild identity theft.

Probably some spammer(s) is(are) sending emails in your name and those spam messages are being bounced back to your mailbox.

You can:

- configure your mail account filters to ignore, flag or delete the
  messages and
- report an incident to a corresponding CERT authority who might try to
  trace the offender

More at:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_emergency_response_team